# How to put data from a buffer to an array in C?

Tags: c

I have got some data in a buffer and want to put those data in an array.

```
 typedef struct chunk 
 {
 char data[300];    /* the bufferr. */
 } CHUNK;
 char *buffer, CHUNK c [100];
```

Assuming I have got data into the buffer, how can I put 300 char per chunk? I'm new to C so please explain me with simple example.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: You haven't specified the question adequately, so all the answers below are credible in some situation and flawed in another.  Are you dealing with textual data (and if so, is it ASCIIZ?, do you want each chunk to be NUL terminated?), or binary data (in which case you need to know the size of the data in buffer).  What you want done with any unused CHUNK data elements/space.

Comment: Yes, my data will be just text file. Until now no idea with the unused CHUNK data. How should I do ? Sorry I'm new to C.

Comment: C normally stores strings as a series of numbers from 0 to 255, with 0 indicating the end of the text, and other numbers representing letters according to the ASCII code (e.g. 32 is a space, 65 a capital 'A').  You need to work out if whatever you will later do with the chunks needs each full 300-character chunk to have its own 0 C-string terminator; ditto for any final partly-filled chunk.  So, how will you use the chunks later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C`, you can copy memory from one area to another using `memcpy()`.  The prototype for `memcpy()` is:

```
void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n);
```

and the description is that it copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dst`, and returns `dst`.

So, to copy 300 bytes from `b` to `a` where both `a` and `b` point to something useful, `b` has at least 300 bytes of data, and `a` points to at least 300 bytes of space you can write to, you would do:

```
memcpy(a, b, 300);
```

Now your task should be something along the lines of:

```
typedef struct chunk 
{
    char data[300];
} CHUNK;
char *buffer;
CHUNK c[100];
size_t i;

/* make buffer point to useful data, and then: */
for (i=0; i < 300; ++i)
    memcpy(c[i].data, buffer+i*300, 300);
```

Comment: one question . since i'm reading from the buffer I can't use the looping you mention since the size of buffer can vary . How should I do ???

Answer (score 3):

The declaration is invalid, but I think you mean:

```
typedef struct chunk 
 {
     char data[300];    /* the bufferr. */
 } CHUNK;

 char *buffer;
 CHUNK c [100];
```

If I understand your question correctly (which I'm far from certain that I do), the code would be something like:

```
 int j = 0;
 char *bp = buffer;
 while (*bp)
 {
     strncpy (c [j] .data, bp, 300);  // copy data into next item
     bp += strlen (bp);
     ++ j;
 }
```

Comment: thx . But It doesn't loop . It only loop for once. what does bp+=strlen(bp) do?

Comment: `bp += strlen(bp)` is the same as `bp = bp + strlen(bp)` which means advance the pointer `bp` by the length of the string.  It would only loop once if buffer had less than 300 characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).

```
strncpy( data, buffer, 299 ) ;
```

Leaving the last index for the termination character `'\0'`. Or make the array size 301 and then use strncpy for 300 elements.

Comment: @kevin - The link given has a simple example and explanation that you can check out.

Comment: Hi when i copy the next 300 char, will it know where to start to copy?

Comment: @kevin - `strncpy` will always start from the starting of the index of the array by default. If needed to started from a different index, give `data+i` where `i` is the position to start from. So if previously copied with any values in `data` will get over written with new values.

Comment: @mahesh - thank a lot :D but one question " how should I loop since the length of the buffer can vary "!!

Comment: @kevin - I didn't understand what you asked. But to write the length of the buffer to data, `toBeReadLength = strlen(buffer); while( toBeReadLength) { strncpy( data, buffer, toBeReadLength ); toBeReadLength = strlen(buffer); }`. But this kind code has a red flag since there is no check for buffer overflows. It works fine as along as the `toBeReadLength` is less than **300**.